# Number of iterations of while loop with increasing step

Tags: python, algorithm

For one of my homework exercises I have to count the number of steps in an algorithm and prove a tightbound however I simply cannot figure out a precise equation for how many times this loop iterates as a function of a list of size n.

```
n = len(A)
value = 0
index = 0
step = 1
while index < n:
    value = A[index] - value 
    index = index + step 
    step = step + 1
```

The step here is increasing by one each iteration so the indices wouldn't increase linearly, I'm struggling with finding an equation to represent how it increases. If I look at a table of number of iterations compared to size n, it looks like it grows like sqrtn but I can't find anything more precise to describe the exact amount of iterations.

Could anyone help me out or guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Comment: There is a well-known formula for the sum of the first N integers, which is the sequence of values your `index` takes...

Comment: Ya I was exploring this and I found that the inverse of the general sum (inverse of n(n+1)/2) gives me something close but still not exact.
EDIT: Ceiling of the inverse is the correct function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code to help you explore this:

```
def calls(n):
    index = 0
    step = 1
    call = 0
    while index < n:
        index += step 
        step += 1
        call += 1
    return call

UPTO = 500        
for i in range(1, UPTO):
    print("{:>4}: {}".format(i, calls(i)))
```

which gives

```
   1: 1    # 1 1    
   2: 2
   3: 2    # 2 2s
   4: 3
   5: 3
   6: 3    # 3 3s
   7: 4
   8: 4
   9: 4
  10: 4    # 4 4s
  11: 5
  12: 5
  13: 5
  14: 5
  15: 5    # ...
  16: 6
# etc
```

**Edit:** OK, the next step: we can see that

```
calls(n) == k such that (k - 1) * k / 2 < n <= k * (k + 1) / 2
```

(`k` is the least integer such that `2 *n <= k * (k + 1)`)

We can introduce delta such that `0 <= delta < 1`, `k' = k - delta`, `2 * n == k' * (k' - 1)`; solve for k', then `k = ceil(k')`, QED.

Comment: Yes, I've done this on my own already, I've gotten close with some equations but nothing precise.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop will run as long as `index < n` (I know you know, bear with me).

Index could be seen as a the following **series**

```
I = 0 , 1 , 3 , 6 , 10 , 15
```

where each term is the previous plus the distance from the start : `index = index + step`. This can be formally written in mathematical terms as

```
S = 0, 1, 3, 6, 10 ..... I(k-1), I(k) 
    ^^^^^^^^^  k terms ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

where

```
I(k) = I(k-1) + k
```

The rate in which `I(k)` approaches `n` (the length of A) is the desired complexity (I believe you've solved a similar problem in class to have such an assignment).